# How to vectorize modulo?

Tags: r, vectorization, modulo

In `R`, I have a vector with integers which shall be checked to be divisible without remainder for multiple values.

```
v <- c(3, 4, 10, 11, 12)
v %% 4 == 0 | v %% 10 == 0 #... this might include 100 checks or more
```

**I'm looking for a vectorization of this (like `v %% c(4, 10)`) which might return a matrix or something similar.**

---

I programmed a function that can do it, but I wonder if there exists already such a function I can reuse instead of "reinventing" it again.

```
`%V%`  <- function(x, y){
  ret <- matrix(nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))
  for(i in 1:ncol(ret)){
    ret[, i] <- x %% y[i]
  }
  return(ret)
}
v %V% c(4, 10)
```

For my initial purpose I would now run `apply(v %V% c(4, 10), 1, function(x) any(x == 0))` or change my function accordingly.

Comment: You can simply do `sapply(c(4, 10), function(i) v %% i)`

Comment: or: `outer(v, c(4,10), '%%')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `outer`-function to achieve what you want:

```
outer(v, c(4,10), '%%') == 0
```

which gives:

> ```
>       [,1]  [,2]
> [1,] FALSE FALSE
> [2,]  TRUE FALSE
> [3,] FALSE  TRUE
> [4,] FALSE FALSE
> [5,]  TRUE FALSE
> ```